# "Type" in specifying a ring/ field

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the [definition of fields on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29#Definition_and_illustration), it says:

> A field is therefore an algebraic structure $\langle \Bbb F, +, \cdot , −, ^{−1}, 0, 1\rangle$; of type $\langle 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0\rangle$, consisting of two abelian groups...

I understand that a field is a set containing a set of numbers, some operations, and some identities, but what exactly does "type" mean in this context?

Comment: The second tuple lists the arity (no. of args) of each operation (constants viewed as a nullary op).

Comment: @BillDubuque Ah.  That actually occurred to me for a second, but then I thought "but subtraction is a *binary* operation so that can't be it".  I just realized that "$-$" might instead mean *negation*.  Thanks.